# Fatal error: Unknown: Failed opening required

Tags: php, wordpress

I get this error when trying to access any part of my domain http://localhost/home/avis-communes/ site wordpress, front or back-end. I tried removing the wordfence plugin through ftp and I still get the following error.

Warning: Unknown: failed to open stream: No such file or directory in Unknown on line 0
Fatal error: Unknown: Failed opening required '/home/avis-communes/wordfence-waf.php' (include_path='.;C:\php\pear') in Unknown on line 0

Any assistance would be appreciated
in file .htaccess :

```
    # BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>

# END WordPress

# Wordfence WAF
<IfModule mod_php5.c>
    php_value auto_prepend_file '/home/avis-communes/wordfence-waf.php'
</IfModule>
<Files ".user.ini">
<IfModule mod_authz_core.c>
    Require all denied
</IfModule>
<IfModule !mod_authz_core.c>
    Order deny,allow
    Deny from all
</IfModule>
</Files>

# END Wordfence WAF
```

Comment: If the problem is in the `.htaccess` you might want to delete it and let wordpress regenerate it for you

Comment: Have you tried removing `php_value auto_prepend_file '/home/avis-communes/wordfence-waf.php'`? See https://docs.wordfence.com/en/After_moving_a_site_or_deleting_some_files,_I_see:_PHP_Fatal_error:_Unknown:_Failed_opening_required_/var/www/html/wordfence-waf.php

Answer (score 4):

It looks like you might somehow have moved or deleted the file specified in the PHP "*auto_prepend_file*" directive (/home/avis-communes/wordfence-waf.php).

This file is related to the Wordfence Firewall "[optimization](https://www.wordfence.com/help/firewall/optimizing-the-firewall/#basic-wordpress-protection-vs-extended-protection)". At this stage, I suggest you [remove the optimization](https://www.wordfence.com/help/firewall/optimizing-the-firewall/#removing-the-optimization) and start over.

Comment: You can get this if you're moving or cloning a WP site. Check both .htaccess AND user,ini for file paths related to your original WP site. Especially if it's a multisite.

Answer (score 4):

There are different scenarios. If you are using the **WordFence Security** plugin, you need to verify the paths in `.user.ini`, `.htaccess`, and `wordfence-waf.php`.
In your case, the path needs to be verified is "/home/avis-communes/".

Comment: I was getting an error after cloning from prod to staging - the .user.ini in the public_html root was cloned along with everything else and was pointing to the prod root. Once i changed it to the staging root, all was well.

Answer (score 2):

Open file .htaccess

close line

## Wordfence WAF

## php_value auto_prepend_file '/srv/www/website.com/public_html/wordfence-waf.php'

## php_value auto_prepend_file '/srv/www/website.com/public_html/wordfence-waf.php'

Answer (score 0):

```
Fatal error: Unknown: Failed opening required '/home/customer/www/domain.com/public_html/wordfence-waf.php' (include_path='.:/usr/local/php73/pear') in Unknown on line 0
```

Then you have to check the `wordfence-waf.php` then you can see the

Domain name with your previous domain you have to correct them
[image]

Now We have to check the web site if the issue is same we have to config the `.htaccess`

[image]

Then that will be fixed.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I installed Wordfence firewall optimization which added a bunch of configuration to my .htaccess. But After deactivating and deleting the plugin, I tried to clear the `/var/www/wordpress/wordfence-waf.php` file.

Because the HTACCESS had an `auto_prepend_file` for this file, my whole site was down.

There are two ways I was able to solve this.

1. Create an empty file with the same name

```
touch /var/www/wordpress/wordfence-waf.php
```

2. remove the config from .htaccess for Wordfence

Ideally, the plugin should have deleted the config inside the HTACCESS. For this, delete everything between the lines `# Wordfence WAF` and `# END Wordfence WAF`.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you didn't install wordpress to yours, so try installing it. Some hosting providers require you to install it separately from their user panel / application panel. Thats how we solved our issue.